# C# Remove "partial" duplicates from collection of arrays

Tags: c#, collections, duplicates

I tried to find the answer for my problem, but I am stucked.
I have collection of arrays and need to remove records where some attributes are same.

Example:
I have attributes - BeginTime, EndTime, Date, Price.

```
07:00, 11:00, 2011-11-14, 90
08:00, 12:00, 2011-11-14, 110
07:00, 11:00, 2011-11-15, 120
07:00, 11:00, 2011-11-14, 50
```

And I want to remove records where BeginTime, EndTime and Date are same and Price is not lowest.
In this example, removed record would be the first one.

Thanks for any help or suggestion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about with LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<Bar> bars = ...

var lowestPriceBars = bars.GroupBy(bar => new { bar.BeginTime, bar.EndTime, bar.Date } )
                          .Select(g => g.OrderBy(bar => bar.Price).First())
                          .ToArray();
```

This works by grouping items with the same timestamps together and then producing, from each group, the item with the smallest price. Do note that if there are multiple items in a group with the same lowest price, the query will retain one of them arbitrarily.

Also note that with a `MinBy` operator (such as one from more [morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)), you could make the `Select` operation more efficient with:

```
.Select(g => g.MinBy(bar => bar.Price))
```

**EDIT**: If you want to keep *all* the items with the lowest price, you can do:

```
var lowestPriceBars = bars.GroupBy(bar => new { bar.BeginTime, bar.EndTime, bar.Date })
                          .SelectMany(timeGroup => timeGroup
                                                   .GroupBy(bar => bar.Price)
                                                   .OrderBy(priceGroup => priceGroup.Key)
                                                   .First())
                          .ToArray();
```

Comment: Wow, I was typing up nearly that exact same answer but you beat me too it... hah...

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to be what I need. I just don't know how to acces names of those attributes, because it not defined anywhere. I just know what is the meaning of value on position 0 etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I changed mz code a little and now it works smoothly